# Syntax Error! >_<

Tags: vb.net

Guy's Cant seem to find my error in VB.Net ! my codes are all right ! but the function still won't save on the database cause of Syntax error in my Insert into statement ! Please help me ! :D!

This is my Code!:D!

```
Dim Transaction As OleDb.OleDbTransaction = Nothing
Dim Connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = Nothing
Try

    Connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(My.Settings.POS_CanteenConnectionString)
    Connection.Open()
    Transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction
    Dim SQL As String = "Insert into Recipt (ReciptDate,ReciptTotal)Values(:0,:1)"
    Dim CMD1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    CMD1.Connection = Connection
    CMD1.Transaction = Transaction
    CMD1.CommandText = SQL
    CMD1.Parameters.AddWithValue(":0", Now.Date)
    CMD1.Parameters.AddWithValue(":1", TextBox4.Text)
    CMD1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    CMD1.Dispose()
    SQL = "Select Max(ReciptID) As MAXID from Recipt"
    Dim CMD2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    CMD2.Connection = Connection
    CMD2.Transaction = Transaction
    CMD2.CommandText = SQL
    Dim ReciptID As Long = CMD2.ExecuteScalar()
    CMD2.Dispose()
    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 0 To DGV3.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim BarCode As String = DGV3.Rows(I).Cells(0).Value
        Dim BuyPrice As Decimal = DGV3.Rows(I).Cells(2).Value
        Dim SellPrice As Decimal = DGV3.Rows(I).Cells(3).Value
        Dim ItemCount As Integer = DGV3.Rows(I).Cells(4).Value
        Dim CMD3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        SQL = "Insert to ReciptDetails" & _
              "(ReciptID,BarCode,ItemCount,ItemBuyPrice,ItemSellPrice)" & _
              "Values" & _
              "(:0          ,:1           ,:2          ,:3          ,:4          )"
        CMD3.Connection = Connection
        CMD3.Transaction = Transaction
        CMD3.CommandText = SQL
        CMD3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":0", ReciptID)
        CMD3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":1", BarCode)
        CMD3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":2", BuyPrice)
        CMD3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":3", ItemCount)
        CMD3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":4", SellPrice)

        CMD3.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CMD3.Dispose()

    Next
    Transaction.Commit()

    Transaction.Dispose()
    Connection.Close()
    Connection.Dispose()
    DGV3.Rows.Clear()
    TextBox4.Text = ""
Catch ex As Exception

    If Transaction IsNot Nothing Then
        Transaction.Rollback()
    End If
    If Connection IsNot Nothing Then
        If Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Connection.Close()
        End If

    End If
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ERROR")

End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think sp parameters are called by `:` prefix, you should use `@` instead. you'll therefore need to replace the .AddWithValue (everywhere) by;

```
CMD1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", Now.Date)
CMD1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", TextBox4.Text)
```

Secondly, I think the Insert syntax isn't right, you've place `TO` instead of `INTO` and space missing. Try this;

```
 SQL = "Insert into ReciptDetails " & _
       "(ReciptID, BarCode, ItemCount, ItemBuyPrice, ItemSellPrice)" & _
       " Values (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)"
```

Comment: ohhh thanks! for a detailed Answer ! thanks a lot ! im having problems with it ! because still studying it ! so I didn't notice it ! thanks!